# Make a layout similar to Google's Play Store

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to make a layout similar to Google's Play Store. I'm having a little trouble identifying the following views.

- Yellow - Is this an ActionBar.Tab or a ViewPager or something else?
- Red - Is this just a RadioGroup with RadioButtons in a Horizontal ScrollView?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the view highlighted with yellow is a TabLayout from support library and the red one is a Horizontal ListView with Chip View

https://github.com/Plumillon/ChipView

Or you can make it your self using a `TextView` with a rounded corner shape drawable as background

Edit: Then you should use a `FrameLayout` instead of `ViewPager` and with `addOnTabSelectedListener` get selected tab on `TabLayout` and show the appropriate Fragment inside `FrameLayout`

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            page = tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition();
            switch (page) {
                case 0:
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment1).commitAllowingStateLoss();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment2).commitAllowingStateLoss();
                    break;
                default:
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment3).commitAllowingStateLoss();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Regarding the TabLayout, I see that almost every time it is used along with a ViewPager. I have already implemented a ViewPager in my app, but the ViewPager is swipeable, and in the Play Store layout you can't swipe to get from one tab to another. Any solution to this? (other than creating a custom ViewPager that derives from the ViewPager class - PS. I have already looked for solutions, that's why I know this)

Comment: Check this: http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Comment: @Amir_P I just implemented it in my app. It's just what I needed. Thanks!